# Sort array(gantt schedule) based on date + duration(min) - with static breaks(date+duration)

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, duration

i have an array based around a gantt schedule. The array contains objects with the following properties

```
{
    id: string;
    startTime: Date;
    durationEstimated: number;
    isBreak: boolean;
}
```

and some generic values. Based on these values i need to loop through the array and sort/update startTime based on previous values. While doing this i also need to take "isBreak" into account(static value – startTime/durationEstimated never changes)

For example, say i have this array:

```
[ 
    {id: '1', startTime: "2020-04-01T08:30:00", durationEstimated: 60, isBreak: false},
    {id: '2', startTime: "2020-04-01T09:00:00", durationEstimated: 15, isBreak: true},
    {id: '3', startTime: "2020-04-01T09:45:00", durationEstimated: 60, isBreak: false},
    {id: '4', startTime: "2020-04-01T10:45:00", durationEstimated: 60, isBreak: false},
    {id: '5', startTime: "2020-04-01T11:45:00", durationEstimated: 60, isBreak: false},
    {id: '6', startTime: "2020-04-01T12:00:00", durationEstimated: 60, isBreak: true},
    {id: '7', startTime: "2020-04-01T13:45:00", durationEstimated: 60, isBreak: false}
]
```

The first **item(id='1')**, will run for 30 min. Then **break(id='2')** for 15 min, and then finish up the last 30 min before starting the next **item(id='3')**. ( New item will never be added to pos 0 )

Say i need to add another object into this ( Starttime is irrelevant )

```
{id: '8', startTime: "2022-05-01T14:30:00", durationEstimated: 60, isBreak: false}
```

I push this into the array at pos 1 the array will then look like this:

```
[ 
    {id: '1', startTime: "2020-04-01T09:30:00", durationEstimated: 60, isBreak: false}, 
    {id: '8', startTime: "2022-05-01T14:30:00", durationEstimated: 60, isBreak: false} 
    {id: '2', startTime: "2020-04-01T09:00:00", durationEstimated: 15, isBreak: true}, 
    {id: '3', startTime: "2020-04-01T09:45:00", durationEstimated: 60, isBreak: false}, 
    {id: '4', startTime: "2020-04-01T10:45:00", durationEstimated: 60, isBreak: false},
    {id: '5', startTime: "2020-04-01T11:45:00", durationEstimated: 60, isBreak: false},
    {id: '6', startTime: "2020-04-01T12:00:00", durationEstimated: 60, isBreak: true},
    {id: '7', startTime: "2020-04-01T13:45:00", durationEstimated: 60, isBreak: false}
]
```

This is where i want to begin sorting and updating the startTime of all elements after the first element. So it should move items around to accomodated breaks.

**Expected result:**

```
[ 
    {id: '1', startTime: "2020-04-01T08:30:00", durationEstimated: 60, isBreak: false}, 
    {id: '2', startTime: "2020-04-01T09:00:00", durationEstimated: 15, isBreak: true}, 
    {id: '8', startTime: "2020-04-01T09:45:00", durationEstimated: 60, isBreak: false},
    {id: '3', startTime: "2020-04-01T10:45:00", durationEstimated: 60, isBreak: false}, 
    {id: '4', startTime: "2020-04-01T11:45:00", durationEstimated: 60, isBreak: false},
    {id: '6', startTime: "2020-04-01T12:00:00", durationEstimated: 60, isBreak: true},
    {id: '5', startTime: "2020-04-01T13:45:00", durationEstimated: 60, isBreak: false},
    {id: '7', startTime: "2020-04-01T14:45:00", durationEstimated: 60, isBreak: false}
]
```

The real array is around 60-80 rows long, and contains multiple breaks + diffrent durationEstimated values.

**Tried**

I always encounter problems when i have to move items around in the array to account for break times.

My thinking is to loop through the array checking every item, comparing it against the previous item(**startTime+duration**)and adding the new date to the current iteration item **startTime**. And then go through every item doing this. The problem is when the breaks are occured, seeing as they are static and never updating.

*Iv'e got it working if you only add new items into the last position of the array(Because i dont need to sort, can only check previous value). But in the real application, new items will be added in any position.*

Comment: I assume the 2022 on id=8 sometimes and not other times is a typo?

Comment: So basically, the time on the breaks should be left alone, but the times of the other items can be changed? Do you have to do this only after the entry has already been inserted at position 1, or can you do it when doing the insertion?

Comment: As i said in my question, the date in the insert object is irrelevant. Will be updated when sorting. 

Sorting needs to be done after insertion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to get it working with the help of Torxed answer.

First i loop through every item and set an endTime

```
items = items.map(item => {
    item.startTime = new Date(item.startTime);
    const endTime = new Date(item.startTime);
    endTime.setMinutes(endTime.getMinutes() + item.durationEstimated);
    item.endTime = endTime;
    return item;
});
```

Next i filter out **real*" and **break** items into arrays

```
const realItems = items.filter(x => !x.break);
const breakItems = items.filter(x => x.break);
```

> Loop through all realItems
>
> Set the **startTime** from previous values **endTime**
>
> Get item **startTime** + **duration** = **endTime**

```
realItems.forEach((realItem, index) => {
    if (index !== 0) {
        realItem.startTime = new Date(realItems[index - 1].endTime);
        const endTime = new Date(new Date(realItem.startTime));
        endTime.setMinutes(endTime.getMinutes() + realItem.durationEstimated);
        realItem.endTime = endTime;
    } else {
        realItem.startTime = new Date(realItem.startTime);
        const endTime = new Date(new Date(realItem.startTime));
        endTime.setMinutes(endTime.getMinutes() + realItem.durationEstimated);
        realItem.endTime = endTime;
    }
});
```

Next i loop through breakItems and check if endTime of an item is >= starttime of the break. In that case i loop through all items after that first response, and add the duration of the break to both startTime/endTime of the items.

```
for (const breakItem of breakItems) {
    const breakStart = new Date(breakItem.startTime).getTime();
    for (let x = 0; x < realItems.length; x++) {
        const realItem = realItems[x];
        const realEnd = new Date(realItem.endTime).getTime();

        if (realEnd >= breakStart + realItem.durationEstimated * 60000) {
            const items = realItems.slice(x, realItems.length);
            for (const item of items) {
                item.startTime = new Date(item.startTime);
                item.startTime.setMinutes(item.startTime.getMinutes() + breakItem.durationEstimated);
                item.startTime = item.startTime;
                item.endTime = new Date(item.endTime);
                item.endTime.setMinutes(item.endTime.getMinutes() + breakItem.durationEstimated);
                item.endTime = item.endTime;
            }
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure how to convert it into JavaScript, but I think I have a solution written in Python that appears to be working.

```py
import datetime, json

data = [ 
    {'id': '1', 'startTime': "2020-04-01T08:30:00", 'durationEstimated': 60, 'isBreak': False},
    {'id': '2', 'startTime': "2020-04-01T09:00:00", 'durationEstimated': 15, 'isBreak': True},
    {'id': '3', 'startTime': "2020-04-01T09:45:00", 'durationEstimated': 60, 'isBreak': False},
    {'id': '4', 'startTime': "2020-04-01T10:45:00", 'durationEstimated': 60, 'isBreak': False},
    {'id': '5', 'startTime': "2020-04-01T11:45:00", 'durationEstimated': 60, 'isBreak': False},
    {'id': '6', 'startTime': "2020-04-01T12:00:00", 'durationEstimated': 60, 'isBreak': True},
    {'id': '7', 'startTime': "2020-04-01T13:45:00", 'durationEstimated': 60, 'isBreak': False}
]

new_data = []

original_data_in_dict_form = {}
breaks = {}
sort_dict = {}
for item in data:
    start_date_obj = datetime.datetime.strptime(item['startTime'], "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S")

    if item['isBreak']:
        breaks[item['id']] = item
        breaks[item['id']]['endTime'] = start_date_obj + datetime.timedelta(minutes=item['durationEstimated'])
    else:
        original_data_in_dict_form[item['id']] = item
        original_data_in_dict_form[item['id']]['endTime'] = start_date_obj + datetime.timedelta(minutes=item['durationEstimated'])

for break_id in breaks:
    for original_id in original_data_in_dict_form:
        if breaks[break_id]['startTime'] > original_data_in_dict_form[original_id]['startTime'] and breaks[break_id]['endTime'] < original_data_in_dict_form[original_id]['endTime']:
            original_data_in_dict_form[original_id]['endTime'] += datetime.timedelta(minutes=breaks[break_id]['durationEstimated'])
        if original_id not in sort_dict:
            sort_dict[original_id] = original_data_in_dict_form[original_id]['endTime']

for original_id, end_time in sorted(sort_dict.items(), key=lambda p: p[1], reverse=False):
    new_data.append(original_data_in_dict_form[original_id])

print(new_data)
```

Sorts on `endTime` and that could obviously be converted to something else. And this is most likely highly inefficient but should probably get you going.